# How should an object's attribute be accessed if it could be a list or a single value?

Tags: python, list, types, attributes

I have an `Event` object that can has many attributes, some of which are single values and some of which are lists of values.

```
class Event(object):
    pass

event = Object()
event.b = [10, 20, 30]
event.c = 15
```

I am trying to access all of the attributes such that I end up with a lot of single values, in a way a bit like this:

```
print(Variable(event = event, name = "b[0]")
print(Variable(event = event, name = "b[1]")
print(Variable(event = event, name = "b[2]")
print(Variable(event = event, name = "c"   )
```

In order to do this, I have created a `Variable` class:

```
class Variable(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        name  = None,
        value = None,
        event = None,
        ):

        self._name  = name
        self._value = value
        self._event = event

        if self._value is None:
            # add magic here
            self._value = getattr(self._event, self._name)

    def name(
        self
        ):

        return self._name

    def value(
        self
        ):

        return self._value
```

I want this variable class to understand that something like "`[2]`" at the end of the specified name means that the attribute is a list and that its element of index 2 should be accessed and set as the variable instance's single value. What would be a good way to do this?

Note that this is a simplified version of what I'm doing -- in reality I am dealing with millions of events and thousands of attributes and I am trying to minimize the amount of code I have to write (and subsequently change) by making the variable class intelligent.

Comment: You can do some testing with something like `isinstance(var, list)` to determine if it's a list or `getattr(var, '__iter__')` to determine if the object is iterable.

Comment: @danielunderwood Thanks for your comment. See, it needs to know which element of the iterable attribute to access, so it has to be able to interpret the name that has been given (e.g. `"b[2]"`) and I'm not sure of an elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an elegant way to do it, but you could use the fact that normal variables shouldn't have brackets to separate the index and then write a function that basically wraps `getattr` with checking for brackets:

```
# Get a variable, index tuple if the name contains an index
def pair_from_name(name):
    if '[' in name:
        parts = name.split('[')
        var = parts[0]
        index = int(parts[-1].split(']')[0])
        return var, index
    else:
        return None

# Basically getattr, but will process indices
def get_var(name, obj):
    pair = index_from_name(name)
    if pair:
        name, index = pair
        iterable = getattr(obj, name)
        return iterable[index]
    else:
        return getattr(obj, name)
```

This isn't really meant to handle extreme name cases or errors, but it'll hopefully put you in the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Yeah, this conceptually makes sense.